# Parse updating object without changing updatedAt

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

The title says it all. I know it sounds a little silly, but it would really help me to do something I want to do. Is it possible to update a ParseObject without changing its updatedAt ?

Comment: I doubt it, as that would defeat the purpose of the field.  You could easily create your own field and manage it as needed though.

Comment: try a way where you take updatedAt last value(may be current before updating) and try to check if you can set it for ParseObject you are trying to update.

Answer (score 1):

It simply is not possible. The `updatedAt` field is changed automatically when ever data in that row (from your Data Browser) changes and there is no way to stop that.

You could always create another column, something like `manualUpdatedAt` (I just came up with some random column name), set it to `Date` and use that field as your `updatedAt` field. The `updatedAt` field will continue to always be updated but `manualUpdatedAt` will only be changed when you want which should help accomplish whatever you want to do.